# Error processing element XXX: CLASS_NOT_FOUND

Tags: java, jar, log4j, log4j2

As part of my work, I'm creating a simple integration of log4j2 with our own custom logging service in my company. For that, I have created two classes: ECSAppender and ECSLog.

ECSLog is a simple class with attributes to standarize what each log will have.
XXXAppender is an Appender that sends the log to our company's web service, centralizing the logs in one place.

I've finished the product and tested it in the same project, and it works fine. However, when I try to package the classes in a jar and import that into another project (which is what we will be requiring our developers), log4j2 is unable to find the classes defined in the jar. I know the classes are being recognized by the program because I'm able to call and run methods of the ECSLog class (a simple print).

What are the configurations required to make an Appender recognizable to log4j2 in a jar?

I've tried: creating a jar through java cvf, through maven clean package, and also going into the jar and editing the MANIFEST to include "Multi-Release:true".

None of these options make the class visible to log4j2.

Log Class and Appenders are working fine. My log4j2.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG" packages="ECSLogging">
<Appenders>
    <ECSAppender name="ECSAppender">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </ECSAppender>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <AsyncLogger name="ECSLogger" level="DEBUG" includeLocation="true">
          <AppenderRef ref="ECSAppender"/>
    </AsyncLogger>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The error i'm getting:

```
2019-11-12 09:32:26,423 ERROR Error processing element ECSAppender: CLASS_NOT_FOUND
```

I expect log4j2 to recognize the appender I've built even though it's in a jar.

Comment: What is the deployment model you're using when running the application that doesn't work? Is it perhaps a WAR, or EAR, or something that is run in an environment with distinct classpaths?

Comment: @ptomli the library is packed in a jar, and the not-working app is being run by Eclipse - so javaw.exe targeting the main method. Simple enough.

Comment: Is the class _really_ called `XXXAppender`? Does your config file specify the package the class resides in? I'm not too familiar with the log4j2 config format, but I'd bet dollars to cents that the error is accurate. Does _nothing_ change between your local test that works, and the used-as-a-jar test that fails?

Comment: Corrected the XXX for clarification. The workflow I'm following is: Select package in Project A -> Export .jar, save in local machine. On project B, add external library from .jar. Methods for the ECSLog class work fine, and log4j2.xml files are identical between projects. Simple main methods in both projects are also identical.

Comment: If you manually unzip the jar you've produced, does it really contain the correct `.class` files, in the correct locations? Is there a `MANIFEST` file? It sounds like your route to getting a JAR file is a little unusual, why not just use maven (or similar)?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for your help. Steps I took: 1. Take Project A (working) and eliminate the package that contained the main method. 2. Using mvn clean package to generate a jar of that new Project. 3. Import that jar into Project B.

Comment: I have this issue too on Log4j 2.17 and am breaking my head trying to understand why. I see from the classloader logging that my custom class is not getting picked up but my static field gets referenced fine at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ptomli for the assistance. Turns out I was packaging the .jar wrong. Steps I took to solve it:
1. Take Project A ( the one that was working) and eliminate the package that contained the main method. 
2. Using mvn clean package to generate a jar of that new Project. 
3. Import that jar into Project B.